# Hot encode data for market basket data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, encode, mlxtend

I have a dataset on which I am trying to determine association rules. The data after the merging and mapping is as follows:

[Transaction data snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XV8Pq.png)

Following this reference: [Market Basket Analysis in Python](http://pbpython.com/market-basket-analysis.html). I see that I can use the `groupby` method to group data using the order ID and using this command:

```
basket = df_order_mapped.groupby(['order_id']).sum().unstack()
```

I am able to group every thing by the order_id with no spaces between the individual products bought. However, I am clueless from here on in as to how to perform one hot encoding as done in the reference. The reference uses the command:

```
basket = (df[df['Country'] =="France"]
          .groupby(['InvoiceNo', 'Description'])['Quantity']
          .sum().unstack().reset_index().fillna(0)
          .set_index('InvoiceNo'))
```

Even though I have tried to understand each individual command one by one but I can't seem to get my head around things. Just as a test I tried to use `groupby` with both the order_id and product_id but I get the error:

```
IndexError: index 838323453 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 838322411
```

The number of rows is 3m and the total number of potential products is 25000.

I would be grateful if someone can help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: instead you should use `from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder` read more here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html

Comment: What are you trying to obtain? A oneHot vector for each combination order_id/product_id?

Comment: Yes, I have tried the onehotencoder.
What I am confused on is if I one hot encode the data before using groupby, how will I merge it in to one row while still keeping the columns

Comment: @Nixon yes. I am trying to obtain a file where each value in product_id is one hot encoded and they are merged according to order_id